# FSharp sequence processing with state

Tags: list, f#, sequence, state

I need to filter data from a long sequence with text lines.
The text lines form records like:

```
{  
    BEGINTYPE1    
    VAL1: xxx
    VAL2: yyy
    ENDTYPE1

    // mix of record types including TYPE1
}
```

I need to keep state during processing:

1. find the record type, thus skipping other text
2. filter the relevant values until the record end is found
3. Continue with 1

I was only able to do this with a List, because a sequence seems 
to read to the end in one expression.
It "seems" you can't process part of a sequence and continue in another expression with the sequence "pointer" at the location where it left off?
So I used a list.
My question, can this processing be done with a sequence
using the standard functions like Skip, filter ... etc?

My List solution:

```
let patLst =  [    
    "VAL1:"         ; 
    "VAL2:"         ; 
    // ..
    ]

let BeginRecord1 = "BEGINTYPE1"
let EndRecord1   = "ENDTYPE1"

let filter (lines:seq<string>) = 
  let llines = Seq.toList lines

  let matchLine inp =  
     let rec loop pat = 
        match pat with 
        | [] -> None
        | h::t -> 
            let m = Regex.Match(inp, h)
            match m.Success with
            | true -> Some (h)
            | _ -> loop t

     loop patLst

  let rec findItem i l = 
    match l with 
    | []    -> []
    | h::t  -> if h=i then  t
               else findItem i t 

  let findItemsUntil u a l =
    let rec loop a l = 
        match l with 
        | []    ->  ([],a)
        | h::t when h=u -> (t , ""::a)
        | h::t -> match matchLine h with
                    | Some(m)  -> loop (m::a) t
                    | None -> loop a t
    loop a l

  let rec loop a l = 
    match findItem  BeginRecord1 l with
    | [] -> List. rev a
    | l2 -> let (l3,a) = findItemsUntil EndRecord1 a l2 
            loop a l3

  llines |> loop  [""] |> List.fold (fun a x -> a + "\n" + x) ""
```

}

Comment: Can you formate your code?

Answer (score 1):

**Aim**
Based on the example code this is maybe not exactly what you are looking for but I thought it would be interesting to do a **single iteration** through the sequence and map the records to concrete types.

**Description**
This solution uses a **state machine** that can be in `Start` or `Collecting`. In `Start` it will expect a "BEGINTYPEx". When finding that it will move into a `Collecting` state that collects properties into a `Map`. When the collecting state hits an "ENDTYPEx" it uses the mapping function to create an instance and adds it to the `Aggregate list`, going back to `Start` state.

**Implementation**
Define some types for the records including a Discriminated Union of those and a state type for the fold:

```
type Type1 = {
    val1:string
    val2:string
}

type Type2 = {
    val1:string
    val2:string
}

type Aggregate =
| T1 of Type1
| T2 of Type2

type State =
| Start of Aggregate list
| Collecting of Aggregate list * string * (Map<string,string> -> Aggregate) * Map<string,string>
```

Define some mapping functions to map a `Map` to the record type:

```
let mapType1 (dic:Map<string,string>) = 
    Aggregate.T1 
        {
            val1 = dic.["VAL1"]
            val2 = dic.["VAL2"]
        }

let mapType2 (dic:Map<string,string>) = 
    Aggregate.T2
        {
            val1 = dic.["VAL1"]
            val2 = dic.["VAL2"]
        }
```

Next we have some Active Patterns to easily decide on a match:

```
let (|Begin|_|) input =        
    match input with
        | "BEGINTYPE1" -> Some ("TYPE1", mapType1)
        | "BEGINTYPE2" -> Some ("TYPE2", mapType2)
        | _ -> None

let (|Prop|_|) input =        
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) then None
    else 
        if(input.Contains(":")) then
            let split = input.Split(":")
            let pName = split.[0].Trim()
            let pValue = split.[1].Trim()
            Some (pName,pValue)
        else None

let (|End|_|) (l,label,f,m) input =        
    match input with
        | "ENDTYPE1" -> Some (List.append l ([f m]), label)
        | "ENDTYPE2" -> Some (List.append l ([f m]), label)
        | _ -> None
```

The actual folder function that moves from one state to the next:

```
let folder state line =
    match state with
    | Start xs -> 
        match line with
        | Begin (label, f) -> Collecting (xs, label, f, Map.empty<string,string>)
        | _ -> failwithf "Should start with a BEGINTYPEx, intead was %s" line
    | Collecting (xs, label, f, m) -> 
        match line with
        | Prop (k,v) -> Collecting (xs, label, f, Map.add k v m)
        | End(xs, label, f, m) (ys, s) -> Start ys
        | _ -> failwithf "Expecting property or ENDTYPEx, instead was %s" line
```

A simple helper method to help easily extract the list:

```
let extractTypeList state =
    match state with
    | Start xs -> xs
    | Collecting (xs, _,_,_) -> xs
```

Finally, the usage:

```
let lines = seq {
        yield "BEGINTYPE1"
        yield "VAL1: xxx"
        yield "VAL2: yyy"
        yield "ENDTYPE1"
        yield "BEGINTYPE2"
        yield "VAL1: xxx"
        yield "VAL2: yyy"
        yield "ENDTYPE2"
    }

let extractTypes lines = 
    lines 
    |> Seq.fold folder (Start [])
    |> extractTypeList
    |> List.iter (fun a -> printfn "%A" a)

extractTypes lines |> ignore
```

Some helpful links:

Learning about [Active Patterns](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/match-expression/#using-active-patterns-instead-of-guards).
Learning about [fold](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/list-module-functions/#19-threading-state-through-an-iteration).

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I first have to study your solution to really understand.

Comment: @RobF shout if you have any questions. I put the code on a gist if you want to grab it in its entirety as an fsx (and the console version in a comment on that gist) https://gist.github.com/dburriss/5407a37f08127679750a73e639665ab5

Comment: @RobF I edited the answer to give more of a description of the solution approach before actual giving the implementation. Hope it helps and happy coding.

Comment: Hi, I understand the idea of processing the list items in the fold function and keep the state in the fold accumulator, never thought about this, smart solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can work with sequences in nearly the same way as lists, you just have to use the `Seq.head` and `Seq.tail` functions instead of the convenient pattern-matching syntax that's available for lists.  Using the built-in functions, your solution would look like this:

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let patLst =  [    
    "VAL1:"         ; 
    "VAL2:"         ; 
    // ..
    ]

let BeginRecord1 = "BEGINTYPE1"
let EndRecord1   = "ENDTYPE1"

let filter (lines:seq<string>) = 
  let matchLine inp =  
     let rec loop pat = 
        match pat with 
        | [] -> None
        | h::t -> 
            match Regex.Match(inp, h) with
            | m when m.Success -> Some (h)
            | _ -> loop t

     loop patLst

  let rec findItem i l = 
    if l |> Seq.isEmpty
    then Seq.empty
    else let h = l |> Seq.head  
         let t = l |> Seq.tail
         if h=i 
         then t
         else findItem i t 

  let findItemsUntil u a l =
    let rec loop a l = 
        if l |> Seq.isEmpty
        then (Seq.empty,a)
        else let h = l |> Seq.head
             let t = l |> Seq.tail
             if h=u 
             then (t , ""::a)
             else match matchLine h with
                  | Some(m)  -> loop (m::a) t
                  | None -> loop a t
    loop a l

  let rec loop a l = 
    match findItem  BeginRecord1 l with
    | s when s |> Seq.isEmpty -> List.rev a
    | l2 -> let (l3,a) = findItemsUntil EndRecord1 a l2 
            loop a l3

  lines |> loop  [""] |> List.fold (fun a x -> a + "\n" + x) ""
```

Now, if you wanted to simplify the logic, you could write your own [Active Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns) to do the same thing as the `head :: tail` pattern for lists.  The active-pattern itself would look something like this:

```
let (|HT|Empty|) s =
    match s |> Seq.tryHead with
    | Some head -> HT (head, s |> Seq.tail)
    | None -> Empty
```

Then your implementation could stay almost identical to your list-based version, just swapping in this active-pattern and replacing the empty lists with `Seq.empty`:

```
let filter (lines:seq<string>) = 
  let matchLine inp =  
     let rec loop pat = 
        match pat with 
        | Empty -> None
        | HT (h,t) -> 
            let m = Regex.Match(inp, h)
            match m.Success with
            | true -> Some (h)
            | _ -> loop t

     loop patLst

  let rec findItem i l = 
    match l with 
    | Empty -> Seq.empty
    | HT (h,t) -> if h=i then  t
                  else findItem i t 

  let findItemsUntil u a l =
    let rec loop a l = 
        match l with 
        | Empty -> (Seq.empty,a)
        | HT (h,t) when h=u -> (t , ""::a)
        | HT (h,t) -> match matchLine h with
                      | Some(m) -> loop (m::a) t
                      | None -> loop a t
    loop a l

  let rec loop a l = 
    match findItem  BeginRecord1 l with
    | Empty -> List.rev a
    | l2 -> let (l3,a) = findItemsUntil EndRecord1 a l2 
            loop a l3

  lines |> loop  [""] |> List.fold (fun a x -> a + "\n" + x) ""
```

Comment: Thanks!
I did not know sequences could be used like this.
I will now first do a performance test on the List and Sequence version.

Comment: To my surprise:
For some file size:
Processing using a sequence: 18.000 msec
Processing using a list:  43 msec
The code is the same:
In both cases:
let flines = File.ReadAllLines file  
For the list case:
let lines = Seq.toList lines

Comment: @RobF Sequences are lazily evaluated, which can be either a benefit or a penalty depending on the usage.  In your case, it sounds like the sequence is being traversed many times.  If the sequence is built by reading lines from a file, this will be extremely expensive.  In such a case, it will almost certainly be better to read the lines from the file once and store them in a list, which is eagerly evaluated.